# How do you add a session message after session_write_close is called?

Tags: session, adminhtml

We use the excellent uRapidFlow module by Unirgy, but have ran into a bit of an annoyance. When you run one of their profiles, they call `session_write_close`. The problem with this is that it means if we wish to run a process from an adminhtml controller we can't set a session flash message to inform the user of success or caught exceptions.

Is it possible to restart the session after the process is complete, in order to add a session message?

I initially wasn't sure if it was possible to restart a session in PHP, but the proof of concept PHP works:

```
session_start();
// if this is the second run, show the value
if (!empty($_SESSION['foo'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['foo'], PHP_EOL;
}
// set an initial value
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';

// start running profile
session_write_close();
// after running profile
session_start();
// set a value to see if it takes
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'foo';
```

I haven't been able to correctly set a flash message on the adminhtml session though. I thought I might be able to call something along the lines of:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
    ->init('core', 'adminhtml')
    ->addSuccess('Whoop');
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you want to show messages to customer during profile execution, you may use $pofile->getLogger() to get instance of logger and pass messages to it. It is not the same as showing them in the page, but you will have record of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
unset($_SESSION);
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
    ->init('core', 'adminhtml')
    ->addSuccess('Whoop');
```

The session isn't lost after `session_write_close()`, if you want to write to the session again you would have to reopen it though. Proof of concept:

```
<?php
session_start();
// if this is the second run, show the value
if (!empty($_SESSION['foo'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['foo'], PHP_EOL;
}
// set an initial value
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';

// start running profile
session_write_close();

// after running profile
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
//// set a value to see if it takes
$_SESSION['test'] = 'foo';
```

Comment: Calling init on the session won't trigger session_start to be called, since it is only called if $_SESSION isn't set (which it seems to be after calling `session_write_close`).

Comment: For anybody interested in doing this, in order to make it function correctly you have to `unset($_SESSION)`. After doing this `init` will reload the session correctly.

Comment: @Cags I have updated my answer, can you check if it's correct?

Comment: The session_start isn't required as it gets called as part of the `init` method call (well in `start` which is called by `init`). Other than that, it should work.

Comment: @Cags Thanks, I updated my answer! I appreciate you coming back with feedback :)